# How can I start a command line application with Crossover from java?

Tags: java, macos, command-line

I have a windows command-line application which must be executed in Mac OSX Lion.
Regarding this issue I've installed Crossover.

The problem now is that I need to start this windows application from a java-Application with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Command");
```

I know how to achieve this with wine in linux but I don't know how to achieve this with Crossover in Mac OSX.

Does anybody know how to do this or rather how to start applications with crossover in a terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, you may however need to update the wine path to the correct folder:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/opt/cxoffice/bin/wine", "--cx-app", "/path/to/someapp.exe"});
```

Also, check out this documentation (Running Windows applications from the command line):
http://www.codeweavers.com/support/docs/crossover-pro/usingcrossover#appruncl